# PySpark 3 higher order function to extract into columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark df ArrayType column ~ ['db1.schema1.table1','schema5.table3','table4']

My objective is to create three ArrayType columns - dbs for example [db1], schemas [schema1,schema5], tables ['table1','table3','table4']

For this, i'd used a python udf which was extremely slow/memory inefficient.

My task is to use pyspark native functions. I'm on spark 3.3.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("WordList", ArrayType(StringType()))])
test_list = [['db1.s1.t1']], [['t3','d1.s1.t1','s2.t2']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)
df = df.withColumn("random",expr("uuid()"))

df=df.select('*',explode("WordList").alias("x"))
df=df.withColumn('x_split',split(col('x'), "\\."))
df=df.withColumn("size", size(col('x_split')))

df = df.withColumn("table", element_at(col('x_split'),col('size')))
df = df.withColumn("database", when(col('size')==3, element_at(col('x_split'),1)).otherwise(lit('na')))
df = df.withColumn("schema", when(col('size')>1, element_at(col('x_split'),col('size')-1)).otherwise(lit('na')))

#then do window collect_set per uuid... then drop duplicates
```

but this risks shuffling at explode/drop duplicates...

Can this be solved using higher order functions?
https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/notebooks/source/higher-order-functions-tutorial-python.html

I tried but couldn't make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first split each value by `.` using the `transform` function.
then when running on the split values, extract the value based on the `size` of the split array.
lastly remove nulls and array_distinct (not a shuffle!)

```
def clean_array(arr):
  return array_distinct(filter(arr, lambda v: v.isNotNull()))


df \
.withColumn(
    'split_words',
    transform(
        'wordlist',
        lambda v: split(v, '[.]')
    )
) \
.select(
    clean_array(transform(
        'split_words',
        lambda v: when(size(v) == 3, v[0])
    )).alias('dbs'),
    clean_array(transform(
        'split_words',
        lambda v: when(size(v) == 3, v[1]).when(size(v) == 2, v[0])
    )).alias('schemas'),
    clean_array(transform(
        'split_words',
        lambda v: when(size(v) == 3, v[2]).when(size(v) == 2, v[1]).otherwise(v[0])
    )).alias('tables')
) \
.show(truncate=0)
```

Comment: @ShivamAnand `clean_array` is defined in the first part of the answer ;-)